# How to include counted property in a query and rename the column in the result in c#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

With Entity Framework-core, I need to select properties from a table in my ASP.NET project and get the counted property and rename it for the query results.
Below is my query code

```
var result = _context.Subjects.Include(s => s.Course).Include(t => t.Topics);
        return View(await result.ToListAsync());
```

In my results, I just need the counted number of topics for each subject instead of the entire topics column and I want to rename it to covered_topics for the resulting table. So, **I need something like t => t.Topics.Count** as **no_of_topics**

I am running ASP.NET-Core 2.2

Please I dont know how to achieve that. I need help.
Thank you for your anticipated guide

Comment: If my solution worked, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Select` a new DTO from your query, like so:

```
public class TopicDTO()
{
    public int NumberOfTopics { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your query:

```
var result = _context.Subjects
                     .Include(s => s.Course)
                     .Include(t => t.Topics)
                     .Select(x => new TopicDTO() 
                      {
                          NumberOfTopics = x.Topics.Count()
                      });

return View(await result.ToListAsync());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this guide. It has opened my eyes to the right direction. However, could you explain whether it could be a good idea to use a viewModel for this since it's intended for presentation in a grid list view page. Also, is there still need for .Include(s => s.Course) and .Include(t=>t.topics)?

Comment: @Josh using a viewModel would be personal preference. The two `.Include()` statements might not be necessary, but I would need to see what the classes for `Course` and `Topic` look like, as well as the `Subjects` context. Using `.Include()` statements will increase performance for larger sets of data.

Comment: `Include`s are redundant - projection queries fall into [Ignored Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes) category.